# Recursive relation of putting $2^k -1$ fixed order elements in a stack

Tags: recurrence-relations

What is the recursive relation showing the possible ways of putting n = $2^k -1$ elements in a stack where always the ith element is in ith place(the element number one is always in first place in the stack). we define the amount of element i, $X(i)$. Always $X(2i)$ or $X(2i+1)$ should not be less than $X(i)$.($X(2i) orX(2i + 1) >= X(i)$) and the minimum amount is 1 unit and maximum amount is n = $2^k -1$ unit.

*In the original problem, the question asked of possible ways to make a syrup with fixed order of elements.

Comment: if the $i$-th element is always in the $i$-th place, then that completely specifies the arrangement. All the other conditions are pointless, because this condition alone tells you exactly where everything is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But the amount of each is not constant.

Comment: Your question is so poorly explained, I can't make any sense of it or your reply. What "amount" are you referring to? You say *the* $i$-th element is in the $i$-th place. For that to be true, there can be only one $i$-th element. So what is $X(i)$ measuring? If there is more than one $i$-th element, where do the rest of them go without violating the $i$-th element in $i$-th place rule? What the heck is a "syrup"? Sounds sticky to me.